# Компоновка в Qt Designer

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, qt-designer

Хочу скомпоновать 2 frame так, чтобы оба имели фиксированную ширину, высота подстраивалась под высоту окна, и оба были прижаты к разным краям. Как это можно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Указать в свойствах `fixed width`, высоту не трогать

Comment: gil9red, не работает данный способ.

Comment: Приложите в вопрос текст из ui-файла

Answer (score 2):

вот вам ui такого

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>578</width>
    <height>437</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>200</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>245</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>100</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>578</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вкратце - компановка вертикальная. обязательно посередине разделитель (фрэйм или сплиттер)
для QFrame - горизонтальная политика fixed + задать минимальный размер